# Detect which button is clicked in Page_Load?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In my asp.net web page, there are a few of buttons and checkboxs. They all can cause postback.
Can I detect which control is clicked? Because I will add code for if clicked a button then do something.
I saw that some examples are done with Jquery.
Can we just do it in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at this article **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163512.aspx**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you not just using the click behavior of the button:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Button id="Button1"
       Text="Click here for greeting..."
       OnClick="GreetingBtn_Click" 
       runat="server"/>
```

**CS**

```
void GreetingBtn_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
}
```

reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx)

Comment: It is a good idea. But I wonder in the case of the combinations of buttons clicked.

Comment: Only one control causes postback, there is no such thing as a combination of button click events.

Comment: AS @pseudocoder said there is no combination of button clicks. You have to have one event handler per button. Then you put the code you want to do in the event handler and that will run when you press that button

Answer (score 1):

You could check `Request.Form["_EVENTTARGET"]` for the control that generated the postback

Answer (score 1):

well if each of the buttons submit a key value to the post or get parameters, and theyre all different it should be pretty easy! :)

```
localhost/home.html?button=clicked&link=selected
```

the above is an example of a get parameter url, you can use jquery to get those, or if its a post you would have access to them in a similar way...the previous page would have to have been a form though.

Answer (score 0):

You could eventually do it by checking Request.Form["_EVENTTARGET"] but that is highly unusual and certainly not necessary.

Whatever you need to do, you can do it in the Click event handler of the given control.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a server hidden control specifying the action (checkbox/textbox/button clicked) using javascript & retrieve that server control in page load to check its action & add your code for that action